# How are the MIN_VERSION_ macros defined for libraries with non-letter characters in their name?

Tags: haskell, c-preprocessor, versioning, ghc, cabal

Cabal, or [more recently GHC itself](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10970), pre-defines CPP macros that allow checking what version of which library is used. It works easily in simple examples like

```
#if MIN_VERSION_base(4,0,0)
... code that works with base-4 ...
#else
... code that works with base-3 ...
#endif
```

However, CPP macro names are more restricted than Cabal package names, so the following does not work:

```
#if !MIN_VERSION_quickcheck-instances(0,3,17)
instance Arbitrary SBS.ShortByteString where arbitrary = fmap SBS.pack arbitrary
#endif
```

```
     error: missing binary operator before token "("
     #if !MIN_VERSION_quickcheck-instances(0,3,17)
     ^
   |
18 | #if !MIN_VERSION_quickcheck-instances(0,3,17)
   | ^
`gcc' failed in phase `C pre-processor'. (Exit code: 1)
```

It doesn't seem to be properly documented how library names like this are handled.

Comment: For dashes in particular they are replaced with `_` apparently, but I'm not sure if or where this is documented.

Comment: You can use [this trick](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.4.2/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#standard-cpp-macros) to list all macros.

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**: the hyphen (`-`) is replaced with an underscore (`_`).

The macros are - as far as I know - generated in the [`generatePackageVersionMacros` function of the `DriverPipeline.hs` file](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/ceb914771aece0aa6d87339227ce406c7179d1d1/compiler/main/DriverPipeline.hs#L2108):

> ```
> generatePackageVersionMacros :: [PackageConfig] -> String
> generatePackageVersionMacros pkgs = concat
>   -- Do not add any C-style comments. See Trac #3389.
>   [ generateMacros "" pkgname version
>   | pkg <- pkgs
>   , let version = packageVersion pkg
>         pkgname = map fixchar (packageNameString pkg)
>   ]
>
> fixchar :: Char -> Char
> fixchar '-' = '_'
> fixchar c = c
>
> generateMacros :: String -> String -> Version -> String
> generateMacros prefix name version =
>   concat
>   ["#define ", prefix, "VERSION_",name," ",show (showVersion version),"\n"
>   ,"#define MIN_", prefix, "VERSION_",name,"(major1,major2,minor) (\\\n"
>   ,"  (major1) <  ",major1," || \\\n"
>   ,"  (major1) == ",major1," && (major2) <  ",major2," || \\\n"
>   ,"  (major1) == ",major1," && (major2) == ",major2," && (minor) <= ",minor,")"
>   ,"\n\n"
>   ]
>   where
> (major1:major2:minor:_) = map show (versionBranch version ++ repeat 0)
> ```

As you can see the `packageNameString` of the package is fixed by performing a `map fixchar` on it. The hyphen (`-`) is replaced with an underscore (`_`). The macro can thus be written like:

```
#if !MIN_VERSION_quickcheck_instances(0,3,17)
instance Arbitrary SBS.ShortByteString where arbitrary = fmap SBS.pack arbitrary
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check the generated macros in `dist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h`.

The macro for `quickcheck-instances` would be named `MIN_VERSION_quickcheck_instances`.